# mouseover effect with jQuery question

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, fade, effect

Let's say I have 4 imagedivs (imgdiv1, imgdiv2, imgdiv3, imgdiv4) and 4 contentdivs (condiv1 condiv2 condiv3, condiv4)and 1 main content div (maincon)
all contentdivs (except the main content div) need to stay "hidden" or invisible. Each con will show up with a fadein effect when I do a mouseover on an imagediv. All contentdivs are in the same place while the imagedivs are a kind of menu.

Example: if I go with my mouse over imgdiv1, condiv1 will appear with a smooth fade in effect. When my mouse goes out of the imgdiv1, condiv1 should fade out to invisibility with a fadeout effect, same goes for imgdiv2, imgdiv3 and imgdiv4. the maincon div will always be there and the condivs should just go over the maincon when triggered with a mousover on imagedivs.

How can I achieve this using jQuery?
What is the best way?

Comment: i'm not a pro with jQuery, I'm looking for some guidance on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the hover function
`$('#imgdiv1').hover(function(){ /*fade in code*/},function(){/*fade out code*/});`

alternatively you could look into JqueryUI and use the Tabs widget.

Comment: which one is the best in your opinion?

Comment: Honestly I have never used the Tabs widget I've only played with the demo at jquery.com and it seemed useful but I can tell you that the hover function is very simple to use and can be added to the element at anytime it's dead simple just check out the specs http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) ? it combines mouse in / mouse out event handers,  minimizing the code you need to write.

Answer (score 0):

You would use hover() to toggle between two functions, one on mouseenter, the other on mouse leaving the imgdiv. For the sake of practicability, give an additional class to your imgdiv: "imgdiv". This allows you to create the behaviour once and attach it to all imgdiv elements , via an each(); loop.

Also, give a class "contentdiv" to all contentdiv elements so you can hide them via one single call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // hide all that should be hidden
   $('div.contentdiv').hide();
    var divToShow= '';
    var strlength = 10;
    $('div.imgdiv').each(function(){
            $(this).hover(function(){
                //find which contentdiv to show
                var thisId= $(this).attr('id');
                strlength = thisId.length;
                divToShow = 'condiv'+thisId.charAt(strlength-1);
                $(divtoShow).stop().fadeIn('slow');
                }
               ,
                function(){
                 // when mouse leaves imgdiv...
                 $(divtoShow).stop().fadeOut('slow');
               }
            );
      });

});
```